# how to receive JSON data from angularjs into laravel

Tags: mysql, angularjs, json, laravel

Help me on this:

I am sending JSON data through angularjs to laravel :

My angularjs Json code like:

```
        $scope.addnew = {name:'',email:'',message:''};
        $scope.addnew.name=$scope.name;
        $scope.addnew.email=$scope.email;
        $scope.addnew.message=$scope.message;

          $http.post("url",$scope.addnew)
        .then(function mysuccess(response) {

           console.log(response.data);

          });
```

Note: I have predefined url in my file.

And I want to receive this JSON file in my laravel controller so that all data can be saved in my mysql table "contactemail" and fields of table are named as name for name, email for email and message for message of user. As I am newbie in Laravel I am not able to do this correctly.Please Help me in this.

Comment: Don't forget to mark answered with the green check mark any of your questions (like the one from an hour ago) if/when you get them answered. [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) ... that's how we roll here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve your input at Laravel using `$request->input('your_json_key')`.

Example basic saving data:

```
$post = new Post();
$post->title = $request->input('title');
$post->save();
```

Those above code will create new post and save it to `posts` table (depends on your model setup).

For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests#accessing-the-request

Comment: I m getting this errors: 1.
QueryException in Connection.php line 761:
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `contact_emails` (`name`, `email`, `message`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (, , , 2016-10-08 11:26:30, 2016-10-08 11:26:30)) And 2.QLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null. My model:public   $fillable = ['name','email','message'];